# api not call using dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to call the api and write the following function in react and using redux

```
export function fetchRecordingJson(file_name) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return axios.post(API_URL+`fetchjson/`, {file_name})
      .then(json => {
        dispatch(receiveJSON(json.data, file_name))
        console.log(dispatch(receiveJSON(json.data, file_name)));
      })
  }
}
```

and call it using the syntax

```
dispatch(fetchREcordingJson(file_name))
```

When it hit the function it not hitting the api and return any result, any one who work on functions using dispatch can help me to understand the issue

Comment: Can you provide a more [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example so we can see how `dispatch` is declared and where you are calling it?

Comment: Take a look at redux devtools and make sure what actions are dispatched and what changes they cause to the state. Check the network tab in the devtools to what xhr are made and what goes wrong.

Comment: the call site for `dispatch(fetchREcordingJson(file_name))` can tell the answer, if you are using `useDispatch` hook this is okay, but if your component is connected to the store using `connect` function then you need to consume the thunk from the `props` like `porps. fetchREcordingJson()` and everything should work fines

Comment: @LouayAlosh  yes my store is connected using connect function but when I am using the method this.props.fetchREcordingJson(file_name) it returns Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions  and same error when using dispatch( fetchREcordingJson(file_name) ))

Comment: did you properly applied the `thunk` middleware? `const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));` [thunk doc](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)

Comment: yes @LouayAlosh issue is resolved as I not applied thunk  const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));  now it works fine after implementing that